# Idea of battery packs conserving energy output seems like it creates contradictions

Tags: forces, work

To me, the idea of energy being conserved in a battery pack seems to create contradictions:

Say we have 2 objects: one weighing 0.1N, the other weighing 0.999N. Lifting both objects directly overhead with 1N of force for 1M will require the same work (F*d) and energy usage (W = change in E). So you would expect a robot doing this task to deplete its battery pack equally for both tasks. But this can't be, right? This would basically be saying that time is irrelevant to energy usage of a robot (it will move the heavier weight slower). So it could press with 1N of force for any arbitrary period of time and consume the same battery pack resources.

(If the answer is basically that I have to assume some sort of idealized robot which doesn't act intuitively, then please explain what's so fundamentally different about humans that requires more ATP expenditure the longer we hold muscle tension (force output))

Can someone make sense of this seeming contradiction to me?

Comment: Don’t understand what you mean by the time period being arbitrary. The rate of doing work is greater for the lighter object but the time it takes to do it is less for the same total energy transferred to the object as the heavier object. What is your point here?

Answer (score 1):

The objects weigh less than 1N.   So by assuming you push on them with 1N of force, you are accelerating them.

By keeping the force constant over a given distance, you are giving them the same amount of energy.

For the lighter one, almost all of the energy given to it is in the form of KE.  The object will be shooting up significantly above the robot when the arm stops.

The idea of "constant force" makes physics problems simple, but they are very rare in real situations.   You would find it almost impossible to apply a constant force for any distance.  Instead, we usually apply *sufficient* forces to move objects at a useful speed.   A robot would probably move an arm at a given speed, and would apply sufficient force for that to occur.

> what's so fundamentally different about humans that requires more ATP expenditure the longer we hold muscle tension

Human muscles "slip" at the molecular level.   They require constant energy expenditure to hold a contracted muscle in position.   If you had a robotic motor that slipped, it would expend energy similarly.

Comment: I still don't know how to think about this contradiction. Aren't we saying that the energy expenditure will be the same regardless of how heavy the thing is that we're lifting? I'm pretty sure that's not how things would work in a real world scenario. I think weight, i.e. time spent holding a force, would expend more battery pack resources.

Comment: Here's another way to put the question: say we pressed with a very large force on an unmovable object, W = 0 since the thing didn't move any distance. But this _must_ expend some battery pack resources. So again I don't see how this energy conservation principle applies to battery packs / robots.

Comment: It's the same if you apply the same force to a heavy object and a light object.  But that's not how things are done.   That's a poor assumption.    We push harder on heavier objects.

Comment: Energy given to the object ≠ energy expended by robot. For similar reasons to why your car's fuel efficiency changes depending on how quickly you are driving (mechanical wear, gearing, etc), it might take vastly different amounts of energy to give that object it's height/speed. If you've ever done what you are suggesting and attempted to use a motor to move an object much heavier than it can deal with, it will quickly heat up and perhaps melt if left to run for too long. The energy is still being expended and lost to internal friction or electrical resistance.